# Want to Not Show title if HoverOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a hover function in jquery that when you hover over an image, it shows its title in div box. suppose all images are together one after another with no space between them, if i start hover from 1st till last of line it shows me title of all. i set the delay of 1 sec

heres code

```
    $('.media-content img').hover(function(e){
var x = -5;
var y = 15;
var detail= $(this).attr('alt');
$('<span class="hovercontent">'+ detail +'</span>')
            .delay(800)
            .css('top', e.pageY + y)
            .css('left', e.pageX + x)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('fast');
            }, function()
            {
             $('.hovercontent').fadeOut(50);
           });
```

In this if i hoverout from image then after a second it display.
I wanted that if I hoverout immediately then the title of that image won't display.
you can say like in operating system when u hover a file it show details if you bypass then it won't. similar i wanted here//

Comment: i accept an answer for previous question

Comment: You have asked 9 questions and only accepted an answer for one of them. In general on Stackoverflow, if you have found an answer to your question to be helpful, you accept the answer. Have you really only found one of your answered questions to be helpful?